# pgbarman recover from streaming backup

Tags: postgresql, barman

I´m currently evaluating pgbarman for production use.

I set up a testserver (postgres 9.6) and barman using synchronous streaming backup.
I know the synchronous streaming works, the WAL file in `~barman/server/streaming` is getting updated.

I can recover using `barman recover` but in the output only transactions until the point where postgres switched the xlog file are present.
So streaming is enabled, I write something to the DB and then I recover, the last write is lost.
If I write, then issue `pg_switch_xlog()` and recover, the write is there.

From this I conclude that the info in the currentlu "open" WAL file is not present in the backup.

How can I get barman to include information from a WAL file that was not switched by postgres at the time of the database failure the in the backup?

Edit: I found out that I can get the information into my recovery directory by putting the partial WAL file into the `pg_xlog` directory. I´d still like a "clean" solution though...

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? I'm in the same situation

Comment: Nope, not yet. Except the workaround I added to the post... :/

Comment: Just created https://github.com/2ndquadrant-it/barman/issues/92